# How can I show next Wednesday's date using php

Tags: php, date

If today is Wednesday, I need to show next Wednesday's date. If today is Tuesday, I need to show tomorrows date.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`strtotime`](http://de.php.net/strtotime) to calculate the time and [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format it:

```
echo date('Y-n-d', strtotime('next Wednesday'));
```

Comment: Perfect phihag. Thanks to everyone else who responded.

Comment: Lifesaver, really nice clean way to do this, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

An option is to use `strtotime()` to get the Unix timestamp for the date, then output it in a  nice format with `date()`.

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("next Wednesday"));
```

---

Aside from `strtotime()`, there is also the `DateTime` class available.

```
$wednesday = new DateTime('next Wednesday');
echo $wednesday->format('Y-m-d');
// or
echo date_format(date_create('next Wednesday'), 'Y-m-d');
```

Using `DateTime` is much more flexible, if you might be needing far future dates (not that next Wednesday is far future!) or further modification of the date.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add to the other helpful answers.  If you wanted not next Wednesday but the Wednesday after, you'd do this:

```
echo date('Ymd', strtotime('+2 week Wednesday'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Very easy, using [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#example-657):

```
 echo strtotime("next Wednesday");
```